# How to create prevent default function for input?

Tags: javascript, html

When a user enters numeric values I just want to display even number I want to set prevent default on odd values.

HTML:

```html
Enter any number: <input type="text">
                  <p id="even"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: what's your actual question?

Comment: When a user enters numeric values I just desire to display even number I want to set prevent default on odd values.

Comment: You have successfully created a function that always prevents the default action. You only didn't use it as a listener.

Comment: @user3838438: What code does display the values? Where does it display them?

Comment: @user3838438: Writing the same thing will not help... We need clarification.

Comment: But this prevents default on all inputs, lets say if user enters 3 I don't want to alert odd number when user enters 4 I want to alert this value.

Comment: you have written an unattached function. It's been defined, but what calls it? (right now: nothing calls it). So can you describe why you wrote what you wrote, what you expected it to do, what you're seeing it do instead, and why you think that is wrong? (in your original post please, not as a reply to this comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an event listener to the input element and validate that the number is even.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c5g6em3t/3)

#### JavaScript

```
var num = document.getElementById('num');
var out = document.getElementById('out');

var isNumber = function(n) { return n == parseFloat(n); }
var isEven = function(n) { return isNumber(n) && (n % 2 == 0); }
var isOdd = function(n) { return isNumber(n) && (Math.abs(n) % 2 == 1); }

var myFunction = function(e) {
    var val = num.value;
    if (isEven(val)) {
        out.innerHTML = val;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};

num.addEventListener('blur', myFunction, false);
```

#### HTML

```html
Enter any number: <input type="text" id="num" />
<hr />
Value: <span id="out"></span>
```

### Update

If you want live validation, change `blur` to `keyup`.

```
num.addEventListener('keyup', myFunction, false);
```

Comment: @user3838438: Yeah, hope it helps get you started.

Comment: sorry just tried when i enters number in input nothing showing in value <div>

Comment: @user3838438: Which browser are you running? I used the blur event so that the code only runs when you move focus away from the input element. Try clicking outside the input after you update the value. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
$("input").mouseup(function() {
  var num = $(this).val();
   if (num % 2) {
     console.log(num);
  }
});
```

EDIT: and [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/ppvLakvf/) in plain JS:

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
el.onkeyup = function () {
    var num = el.value;
    if (num % 2 == false) {
        console.log(num);
    }
};
```

Comment: as additional note: this is not plain JavaScript but jQuery, so if you've never used that before, you'll need to learn jQuery's way of doing JavaScript to go along with this snippet.

Comment: This question is not tagged jQuery. Please avoid using it without an explicit recommendation why it would be needed here.

Comment: Thanks Bram but i want in core javascript not Jquery.

Comment: on a modern JS note, `document.querySelector("input")` is generally more obvious than `document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];` (and more portable if the element selector changes)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to detect an odd value, you could use something like

```
function whatever(e){
    if(value % 2 != 0){
        e.preventDefault()
    }else{
        //Do something
    }
}
```